# python migrate virtualenv to another server then can not work

Tags: python, virtualenv

I develop my project on the development environment with python2.7 and virtualenv.

I install python2.7 because of the default python is python2.6 on my development environment and I create virtualenv with:

```
virtualenv -p python2.7 ums_env
```

It is work until I finish my job.

Then I copy this folder(ums_env) to **another server which has no python2.7 only python2.6** and start with:

```
. ums_env/bin/activate
```

[image]

It seems like the python virtualenv(ums_env) do not work well.

What is wrong with this? If I forget some steps to migrate virtual env from one server to anthor server?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not supposed to copy a virtualenv to another machine but to rebuild it (using a pip requirements file that is to be part of your project).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is right : virtualenv use a lot of hardlinks and is not meant to be transported. Maybe what you are looking for is a container solution like docker.

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers and Setop.It seems that I use virtualenv the wrong way.I will try to rebuild it and pip install what i need or maybe i should to have a look to docker.